# AngularJS Оптимизация

Tags: angularjs

Из таблицы №1 происходит выборка, и в некоторых случаях нужно один из её параметров (rid) передать в функцию, которая возвращает массив строк  из таблицы №2.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in item">
{{event.date}}
{{event.name}}
{{event.number}}
 <div ng-if="event.class == 'image'">
  <div ng-init="record(event.rid)">
   <div ng-repeat="rec in records"
     {{rec.filename}}
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Функция record:

```
$scope.record = function(rid) {
                console.log('Отправляем: '+rid);
                $http.get('http://site.ru/dev/filename/'+rid)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        console.log('Ответ: ',  response.data);
                        $scope.records = response.data;
                    }, function error(err) {
                        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
                    });
            };
```

Мне сказали что ng-init в данном случае очень жирный костыль. Возможно ли данный код как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: в коде логическая ошибка: если будет несколько элементов event, Для которых будет выполняться `"event.class == 'image'"` то в обоих случаях records будет ссылаться на одно и то же.

Comment: Уже голова квадратная от всего) Как это поправить?